# Posting a form with several form fields and file using PHP curl

Tags: php, file, curl, multipartform-data

I am trying to post a form with some text input fields to my api, I also want to upload a file to the server at the same time. I did some research and came up with the following code as per suggestions from various websites, but it does not seem to work.

**First Approach:**

```
 $cfile = new CURLFile('/home/xyz/myimge.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'mymage.jpg');

 $params = array(
 "userid_id" => "some id #",
  "file" => $cfile,
  "name" => "test_file",
  "gallery" => "myalbum"
  );

 $uri = 'http://myserver.com/somedir/';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

  $response_data = curl_exec($ch);

  //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

  //var_dump($response_data);
  curl_close( $ch );
  unset( $ch );
```

**Second Approach:**

```
$cfile = new CURLFile('/home/xyz/myimge.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'mymage.jpg');

$params = array(
 "userid_id" => "some id #",
  "name" => "test_file",
  "gallery" => "myalbum"
  );

$params = array('item' => http_build_query($params), 'file' => $cfile );


  $uri = 'http://myserver.com/somedir/';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

  $response_data = curl_exec($ch);

  //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

  //var_dump($response_data);
  curl_close( $ch );
  unset( $ch );
```

As per documentation, passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as multipart/form-data. and I should get my form fields as $_POST array and the uploaded file as $_FILES array. Using both of these approaches, I get all my form fields in my receiving php template as post variables, but I do not get the file.

When I check the ccurl_getinfo output for content_type, I see it is :
["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "text/html"
and not "multipart/form-data" as suggested in the documentation. Setting the content_type explicitly as "multipart/form-data" using curl_setopt also does not have any effect.

Many forums suggest using '@'.$filename format for submitting the file, but this seems to be deprecated as per PHP documentation. I am on PHP 5.5, and suggested way of uploading the file is forming a CURLFile object, which is what I am doing here.
Can any one suggest what is wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your approach is perfect, but there is a silly mistake.
You can try by adding extra header information. Hope it will work.

```
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```